# WP7 & Linq-To-Sql: Retrieve distinct recordset of specified column

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I'm converting an existing data project to Windows Phone 7. There's a method that accepts a string value and uses it as a column name to select a distinct list of values:

```
public static List<string> GetDistinctValues( string Field ) {
    string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [" + Field + "] FROM [MyTable]";
    ...
}
```

Converting this to Linq-to-Sql, I know how to use `Distinct()`, but I don't know how to dynamically set which column to query. I've tried searching and haven't found much. There are maybe a dozen different columns that may be used.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question originally.

What you are trying to do can be accomplished using [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

```
public static List<string> GetDistinctValues( string Field ) 
{
    var query = db.MyTable.Select(Field).Distinct();
    ...
}
```

Comment: The linked samples are using classes unavailble on Windows Phone.